# React and bootstrap without importing and embedding into application

Tags: reactjs, bootstrap-4, sass, mixins

We all know how to `import` Bootstrap into an application (in this case `React`) but what happens when my `React` application will be embedded into a website that already has Bootstrap added as an external library?

I am familiar with the classes that Bootstrap offers and they are pretty straight forward to use as well but where things are tricky is when I need `Mixins`, and specifically those for responsive design:

```
@include media-breakpoint-up(sm) {
   @include make-col(6);
}
```

Is there a way to use that without having to include Bootstrap in my React application and possibly overwrite some of the updated values coming from the parent site? Or would it make more sense for me to declare my own breakpoints?

```
@media (min-width: 576px) { ... }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, it would be better to add a custom breakpoint Mixins and use it and it would make more sense since you don't have to depend on Bootstrap.

Something similar to this.

```
// breakpoint.scss

$breakpoints: (
  "sm": 640px,
  "md": 768px,
  "lg": 1024px,
  "xl": 1280px,
  "xxl": 1536px,
) !default;

@mixin breakpoint-up($width) {
  @if map-has-key($breakpoints, $width) {
    @media (min-width: map-get($breakpoints, $width)) {
      @content;
    }
  }
}

@mixin breakpoint-down($width) {
  @if map-has-key($breakpoints, $width) {
    @media (max-width: (map-get($breakpoints, $width) - 1px)) {
      @content;
    }
  }
}

@mixin breakpoint-between($fromWidth, $toWidth) {
  @if map-has-key($breakpoints, $fromWidth) {
    @media (min-device-width: map-get($breakpoints, $fromWidth)) and (max-device-width: (map-get($breakpoints, $toWidth) - 1px)) {
      @content;
    }
  }
}
```

Hope this helps :)

Comment: Thanks! That is what I end up doing, we do have to use boostrap for the rest of the application so it has to be a combination of both.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to let me know that you found my answer valuable.